# Cant access key values from an Object in Reactjs after fetching

Tags: json, reactjs, object

I have a user details page in Reactjs where I'm fetching the user details and populating it to the corresponding fields. But I'm not able to access key values from the user object.

My sample code is

```
function EditProfile(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
            const profileConfig = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.token
                }
            };
            fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/user/me`, profileConfig)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log("response: ", response.user);
                if (response.success === true) {
                    setUser(response.user)
                } else {
                    alert(response.message)
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                alert('User fetching faied: ' + error)
            })
        }
        fetchUserInfo()
    }, [])

    return (
       <div>{user.name}</div>
    )
}
```

The response from the server (user object is)

```
{
  "status": true,
  "_id": "5ecfdc403165f709b49a4a0e",
  "name": "Anand OL",
  "gender": "male",
  "dob": "2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  "email": "anand@gmail.com",
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "createdAt": "2020-05-28T15:44:00.700Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-01T08:38:37.902Z",
  "__v": 136,
  "image": "5ecfdc403165f709b49a4a0e_Image.png"
}
```

when I try to access name from the user object like `user.name`
I'm getting an error **user is not defined**

Comment: The issue is solved by adding [] in useState of the user object ```const [user, setUser] = useState([])``` Like this solved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, but that is because now 'user' is a defined array and `user['name']` is returning `undefined`. You should only do this if you expect your state to be an array, and conditionally render on `user.length && user.map(...`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide some initial state to display (or conditionally render) while the fetch is occuring.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(); // <-- user is undefined!!
```

Conditionally render UI

```
return <div>{user && user.name}</div>;
```

or

```
return user ? <div>{user.name}</div> : null;
```

*Note: Use caution with the former as not all falsey values are created equal, i.e. Consider `return <div>{value && value.property}</div>`, if/when `value = 0` a falsey value, then a "0" will actually be rendered.*

Or you can provide some default state

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: '' });
```

Comment: for conditional render, you can just do `{ user && <div>...</div> }`. React ignores `{false}` values. I prefer your latter suggestion.

Comment: @JosephD. True, except for the times when what you are conditionally rendering is the *only* thing returned.

Comment: `return false` would just mean this component has nothing to be rendered. Right? :)

Comment: @JosephD. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've read that clause. React also stated "If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.". Note that there's a root element in DOM where we mount the component. Thus, returning false from a component would just basically be `<div id="root"></div>`. See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/fast-rgb-b1pmw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @JosephD. Obligatory pointing out that `undefined` is falsy, not false, i.e. `undefined === false` is a false statement. It's a bit of a grey area one can get into if they aren't careful and/or explicit about what is *actually* being returned from any complex conditional test.

Comment: Certainly agree to that! Guess that was your point all along. :)

Comment: one more help guys, I need to convert this ```2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z``` to ```dd/mm/yyyy``` format

Comment: @LijomonCJohn Better to open a new question, but [here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-fully-specified-date-string-to-formatted-date-ddmmyyyy-5iwjf?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) my quick stab at it if all you need is string manipulation. If that doesn't work for you then please open a new question and list all your requirements and restrictions (You can share a link here). My go-to for handling/manipulating DateTime objects is `luxon`.